# Android PhoneGap Cordova v 4.1.1 WebService calls are not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Working on Cordova Version 4.1.1, Android app able to run but Web services calls are not working. In WebApp all web service calls are working. Please share your thoughts on this issue.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the cordova whitelist plugin. It will resolve the issue.

Comment: I have installed but same issue

Comment: I have downgrade the Cordova version from 5.1.1 to  3.5.1. It is working now.